# PHP count some rows

Tags: php

I have a problem, I want to create a function which counts the data from the Database. But I want that from the column to count some ID's and not all rows.

My code that doesn't work:

```
function countMember() {
    include("./config/config.php");
    $fetch_countMember =   $fetch_countMember->prepare("SELECT * FROM `accounts`");
    $fetch_countMember->execute();
    while($fetch_countMember=   $fetch_countMember->fetch()) {
    if($fetch_countMember["member"] == 5 || $fetch_countMember["member"] == 6 || $fetch_countMember["member"] == 12 || $fetch_countMember["member"] == 13 || $fetch_countMember["member"] == 14 || $fetch_countMember["member"] == 15 || $fetch_countMember["member"] == 16 || $fetch_countMember["member"] == 17 || $fetch_countMember["member"] == 20 || $fetch_countMember["member"] == 21)
        $c_member++;
    }
    return $c_member;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error? For the count part it would be best if you could change the query to something like: SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE member IN (...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [PDO::exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

elegant way to do it:

```
$pdo = new PDO(....);
$ids = [5,6,12,13,14,15,16,17,20,21];
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE member IN (%s)", implode($ids, ','));
$count = $pdo->exec();
echo $count;
```